Completeness of $\sin(kx)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ in $L_1[1, 4]$
I am reading a function analysis book and having trouble proving the following task: is ${\sin(kx)}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ complete in $L_1[1, 4]$?
I understand that completeness in $C[1, 4]$ implies completeness in $L_1[1, 4]$, but I'm having trouble with this task because I can not use the following theorem (which is usually used to prove such facts):

Trigonometric system $\frac{1}{2}, \cos(kx), \sin(kx)$ is complete in a space of continuous 2-pi periodic functions

The problem is that $4 > \pi$, and I'm confused about how to handle this. Any help would be highly appreciated.
UPD: what if there would be system ${\sin(kx)}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, would it change something?

What do you mean by completness ? That there is no function orthogonal to each $\sin(kx)$ ?

@RyszardSzwarc, definition: system $X$ is complete in space $L$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$ and for each element $f \in L$ there is $\tau = Lin(X)$ - linear combination (finite) of elements from $X$ such that $\lVert f - \tau \rVert_L < \epsilon$

The system is not complete in $C[1,4].$ The function $1$ cannot be uniformly approximated by $X$ as all the functions in $X$ vanish at $\pi.$ Still it can be complete in $L^1(1,4).$

@RyszardSzwarc, thanks for your idea. I will try to prove that it's not complete in $C[1, 4]$ now. But how can we prove completeness in $L_1[1, 4]$ then? I mean, the most obvious way is just to say that it follows from completeness in $C[1, 4]$ which is not the case here..

The system may be still complete in the subspace of $C[1,4]$ consisting of functions vanishing at $\pi.$

We have $\sin n(\pi+x)=(-1)^n\sin nx.$ Let $$g(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & 2\pi -4\le  x\le 4\\
0 & {\rm otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\int\limits_1^4g(x)\sin nx\,dx =\int\limits_{2\pi-4}^4\sin nx\,dx=(-1)^n\int\limits_{\pi-4}^{4-\pi}\sin nx\,dx=0$$ It means the bounded linear functional on $L^1(1,4),$ given by $\varphi(f)=\int\limits_1^4g(x)\,f(x)\,dx$ vanishes on the closed linear span of the system $\{\sin nx\}_{n=1}^\infty.$
Hence the system is not complete.
Remark The crucial property is that $1<\pi<4.$
In a similar way we can prove that the system $\{\cos nx\}_{n=0}^\infty $ is not complete in $L^1(1,4).$ This time we consider  $$h(x)= \begin{cases} \ \ \ 1 & 2\pi -4\le  x\le \pi \\
-1 & \pi  \le x\le 4\\
0 & {\rm otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$ and notice that $$\int\limits_1^4 h(x)\cos nx\,dx =0$$
